# Symfony2 How to find records which starts with specified character?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How to find records which starts with specified character?

for example: only users where username starts with the A

User class

```
    <?php

    namespace DemoBundle\Entity;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
         */
        protected $lastname;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // your own logic
        }
  //getters and setters
    }
```

and controller action with solution @Kwido

```
public function listAction($letter)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
            ->select(['user'])
            ->from(User::class, 'user')
            ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->like('user.lastname', ':lastname'))
            ->setParameter('lastname', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('A%'));

        $result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

        die(var_dump($result));
}
```

this is all what I have. This give me error

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getEntityManager" of
>   class DemoBundle\Controller\DefaultController"

Comment: In the controller class to get EntityManager you need to invoke `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` instead of `$this->getEntityManager()`. Changed it and try again.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But query return null. In database I have about 4k random users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi @Damian change your code to it.

```
public function listAction($letter)
{
    $result = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getManager()
                     ->createQueryBuilder()
                     ->select('u')
                     ->from(User::class, 'u')
                     ->where('u.lastname LIKE :lastname')
                     ->setParameter('lastname', 'A%')
                     ->getQuery()
                     ->getResult();

    dump($result);

    // return response bellow
}
```

When the page is loaded click in the Symfony profiler bar and go to database section. Look the generated query and try run it directly on database.

Answer (score 0):

Use the querybuilder `Like` expr of Doctrine:

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->like('u.firstname', $qb->expr()->literal('Gui%'))
public function like($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Comparison instance
```

To use the `Like` expression within your **Repository** class:

```
// getEntityManager() = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select(['user'])
    ->from(User::class, 'user')
    ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->like('user.userName', ':userName'))
    ->setParameter('userName', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('A%'));

$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: I've absolutely no clue how your code looks like so I just made gave you a basic solution. You don't state which error it gave you so it's really hard to help you. You should proivde more information if you want people to help you. As for the querybuilder the mapping might be of as in `userName` could be `username` as I've got no clue how your entity is mapped and don't know which properties your entity contains. So tweak it to your liking or provide more information for further assistance.

Comment: I added a new answer to your solution